# What's the difference between "rows scan" and "page limit" in mysql?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have a `SELECT` sentence in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_flows` WHERE deleted = 0 AND status = 0 AND end_time > '2022-02-03 13:54:48.173'
```

and there are indexes in columns `deleted`、`status` and `end_time` and a primary key `id`.

I wan't to get all the results for processing and I have two ways:

1. use `rows scan` like this in `gorm`:

```golang
rows, err := db.Model(&ModelInfo{}).Where(...).Rows()
// ignore error judge
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    ....
}
```

2. use `page limit` which I record the latest `id` for next page:

```golang
var latestId int64
for {
    var result []*ModelInfo
    err := db.Where(...).Where("id > ?", latestId).Order("id").Limit(10).Find(&result).Error()
    // ignore error judge
    if len(result) == 0 {
        break
    }
    for _, r := range result {
        .......
        latestId = result.Id
    }
}
```

I want to know which is the best? Please help me, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should use offset method. also order by id.

```
var page int
for {
    var result []*ModelInfo
    db.Model(&model{}).Where(...).Offset(10 * page).Limit(10).Order("id").Find(&result).Error()
    if len(result) == 0 {
        break
    }
    page++
    for _, r := range result {
        .......
        latestId = result.Id
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I think `Order` is good but `Offset` is time-consuming when there are a lot of pages (for example, there are 1,000,000 pages record for query). Using page + latestId seems work fine because it will use index, not skip too many unused rows and not consume lot of memory for storage. The questions is what it would to do when I just scan rows (using first choice)? It would consume a lot of memory or keep too many connections? It would use index? I'm not sure about that and need for your help, thanks.